# Seasons validation

Tags: php, validation, date

I have an array with seasons:

```
$seasons = [
  [1, 4, 13, 6], //April, 1th - June, 13th
  [20, 1, 2, 8], //January, 20th - August, 2th
];
```

I need to validate them by the following rules:

1. Seasons can't intersect like in this example
2. Seasons must border on each other (if some season ends on August, 15th, next one should be started on August, 16th)
3. In the sum all the seasons should be 1 year

Does someone have an experience with such a task?

Comment: please provide your attempts so far so we can help. People are rarely inclined to code for you without evidence of effort.

Comment: @Visualife thank you for hint